# Discord.JS Message Edit

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to edit the message over and over again.
So I made variable

```
this.msgRef = await channel.send({ embeds: [embedMessage] });
```

If I want to edit I use

```
this.msgRef.edit(...)
```

If the bot for some reason disconnects, he will lose msgReference.
Because of that, I saved it to DB.
How to create a message again because Message (object) in Discord.JS have a private constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the message again, you can simply fetch the channel's messages every time you bot connects (on the ready event for example) like so

```js
client.on('ready', () =>{
  const messages = await channel.messages.fetch()
  client.msgRef = messages.find(msg => msg.author.id === client.user.id
    && msg.embeds[0]
   // Etc.. Add as many conditions to make sure you choose the right message
);
})
```

This way, use `client.msgRef.edit(...)` whenever you want.